# Audio mixing algorithm changing volume

Tags: c++, algorithm, audio

I'm trying to mix some audio samples with the following algorithm:

```
short* FilterGenerator::mixSources(std::vector<RawData>rawsources, int numframes)
{
short* output = new short[numframes * 2]; // multiply 2 for channels

for (int sample = 0; sample < numframes * 2; ++sample)
{
    for (int sourceCount = 0; sourceCount < rawsources.size(); ++sourceCount)
    {
        if (sample <= rawsources.at(sourceCount).frames * 2)
        {
            short outputSample = rawsources.at(sourceCount).data[sample];
            output[sample] += outputSample;
        }
    }
}

// post mixing volume compression
for (int sample = 0; sample < numframes; ++sample)
{
    output[sample] /= (float)rawsources.size();
}

return output;
}
```

I get the output I want except for the fact that when one of the sources are done, the other sources start playing louder. I know why this is but I don't know how to solve it properly.

Also, this is a screenshot from Audacity from the audio I output:
[image: Audacity Screenshot]

As you can see there's definitely something wrong. You can see that the audio hasn't got zero at the center anymore and you can see the audio getting louder once one of the sources are done playing.

Most of all I'd like to fix the volume problem but any other tweaks I can do are very appreciated!

Some extra info: I know that this code doesn't allow mono sources but that's ok. I'm only going to use stereo interleaved audio samples.

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but you should allocate the buffer once and re-use it. You want to avoid memory allocation in performance critical code. (I'm assuming this is headed for a sound card and not a file.)

Comment: This is heading to a file. I'm editing audio non-realtime. I know that I can do some things more performant but that isn't the issue right now. It does what I want very fast at the moment

Comment: @JohnK: Don't sweat it. Modern allocators are surprisingly efficient, and audio is very slow in comparison to CPU's. Allocating a 1 kB buffer is easily a thousand times faster than playing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually mixing don't divide by the number of sources. This mean that mix a normal track with a mute track can halve its amplitude. If you want you can eventually normalize the track so that it is in his range.

The code is not tested, there may be errors:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::max 
#include <cmath>     // for std::fabs

short* FilterGenerator::mixSources(std::vector<RawData>rawsources, int numframes)
{
  // We can not use shorts immediately because can overflow
  // I use floats because in the renormalization not have distortions
  float *outputFloating = new float [numframes * 2];

  // The maximum of the absolute value of the signal 
  float maximumOutput = 0;

  for (int sample = 0; sample < numframes * 2; ++sample)
  {
      // makes sure that at the beginning is zero
      outputFloating[sample] = 0;

      for (int sourceCount = 0; sourceCount < rawsources.size(); ++sourceCount)
      {
          // I think that should be a '<'
          if (sample < rawsources.at(sourceCount).frames * 2)
              outputFloating[sample] += rawsources.at(sourceCount).data[sample];  
      }

      // Calculates the maximum
      maximumOutput = std::max (maximumOutput, std::fabs(outputFloating[sample]));
  }  

  // A short buffer
  short* output = new short [numframes * 2]; // multiply 2 for channels

  float multiplier = maximumOutput > 32767 ? 32767 / maximumOutput : 1;

  // Renormalize the track
  for (int sample = 0; sample < numframes * 2; ++sample)
      output[sample] = (short) (outputFloating[sample] * multiplier); 

  delete[] outputFloating;
  return output;
}
```

Comment: So you would leave the division out of it and then use some kind of compression?

Comment: During the mix you can calculate the maximum of the absolute value of the output signal, and then divide by the maximum each sample (only if it exceeds the maximum range of course)

Comment: So I would have to have some kind of Linear Dynamic Range Compression? (reaction to comment below)

Comment: I was wrong thinking you have floating point in the range [-1,+1]. for short must renormalize the maximum signal with the maximum storable in short

Comment: It depends on what you want, you can use a dynamic compressor or fixed based on the maximum value assumed by the signal

Comment: Could you link me to an example? I guess that, for now, the maximum value (which should be the simplest I guess) would be okay

Comment: Typically mixing routines mix large samples in blocks. If you normalize to maximum sample per block you will have volume discontinuities between the blocks. Most audio software will apply a fixed gain and then clip the sample with something like this  sample_short = 32767* max(-1,min(1, gain * sample_float))  [side note: floating point mixers assume the input waveforms are normalized to -1..1]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're adding up everything into a `short` before you divide, you're probably getting overflow. You need to add to an intermediary that's bigger. Also the final scaling shouldn't be dependent on the number of samples, it should be a constant - determine it *before* you call your function.

```
short* FilterGenerator::mixSources(std::vector<RawData>rawsources, int numframes, double gain = 0.5)
{
    short* output = new short[numframes * 2]; // multiply 2 for channels

    for (int sample = 0; sample < numframes * 2; ++sample)
    {
        long newSample = 0;
        for (int sourceCount = 0; sourceCount < rawsources.size(); ++sourceCount)
        {
            if (sample <= rawsources.at(sourceCount).frames * 2)
            {
                short outputSample = rawsources.at(sourceCount).data[sample];
                newSample += outputSample;
            }
        }
        output[sample] = (short)(newSample * gain);
    }

return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to do the "post mixing volume compression". Simply add up all the sources and don't allow the sum to overflow. This should work:

```
short* FilterGenerator::mixSources(std::vector<RawData>rawsources, int numframes)
{
short* output = new short[numframes * 2]; // multiply 2 for channels

for (int sample = 0; sample < numframes * 2; ++sample)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (int sourceCount = 0; sourceCount < rawsources.size(); ++sourceCount)
    {
        if (sample < rawsources.at(sourceCount).frames * 2)
        {
            short outputSample = rawsources.at(sourceCount).data[sample];
            sum += outputSample;
            output[sample] += outputSample;
        }
        if (sum > 32767) sum = 32767;
        if (sum < -32768) sum = -32768;
        output[sample] = (short)sum; 
    }
}

return output;
}
```